# Method to assigned value to array using loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, matrix

How to write a method to assigned a set of values through a loop to a multidimensional array?

```
double [][] A = new double [3][3];// 
    A_array[0][0]=1;
    A_array[0][1]=2;
    A_array[1][0]=3;
    A_array[1][1]=4;
```

I could write the above way, but I am looking to do it "dynamically";

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     double [] [] a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

Then a method to assigned the above values in an array:

```
public class matrixloop {

private double [][]a;

public matrixloop ( double [][] a)

{
    this.a=a;   
}

public double [][] assigned_1 (double [][] a)

{ 
    for (int c=0; c<3; c++)
        for (int d = 0; d<3; d++)
        this.a[c][d]=a[c][d];
        return a;

}
```

But this method is not working,

Comment: also I am not looking to assigned a sequences of number to the multidimensional array

Comment: what do you mean by `method is not working`?you are simply copying the array ?

Comment: the method I wrote is not working, I want to give a set of values in the main class, then a method will assigned them to an array. for Example  I want 1 to be at [0][0], 5 at [0][1], 8 at [0][2] and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm not entirely sure about the question but I'll try and answer. Basically you want to deep copy a matrix? There are several issues here:

1. I think an important style tip is that class names should start with a capital letter. I know it's not going to fix everything but it's good practice.
2. You should try surrounding your for-loop with some braces there- another style tip but one I think is important for beginning programmers (don't want dumb syntax errors)
3. If you want to loop a matrix 'dynamically' then you should be able to adjust your length. In short- don't just put a 3 there but rather use the length property of an array.

And before I get caught up in anything more I'll send you to some (hopefully) helpful resources:

[Java array tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_arrays.html)
[Java style- because I think it's important...](http://www.javaranch.com/style.jsp)
[Multi-Dimensional arrays](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html)

I hope this has been helpful.

=== EDIT ===

If you want to transpose a 3*3 matrix, then you can do that with for loops like this:

```
public double[][] transpose( double[][] oldMatrix ){
    int size = 3;
    double[][] newMatrix = new double[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            newMatrix[j][i] = oldMatrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return newMatrix;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the links and advises, basically I am looking to transpose a 3*3 array (matrix), so I would initialize a 3*3 matrix, performance certain calculation (such as find the determinant...) then I would transpose it so something like b[j][i]=a[i][j], so in order to  do that I thought I would have to address the array size as a[i][j]

Comment: I edited my answer to have an example of transposing a 3*3 matrix. It would be good practice to extend it to ANY size matrix (2*7, 9000*9000, etc.)